# SSRS Charting - Display Legend and Percent

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, charts

I'd like to display Day (Percentage) eg Fri (22%) on the chart

Can do each individually:

Series Label Properties, Label data:  #PERCENT{p0}

or:  =Fields!DayOfWeek.Value

**Problem:** How to display both?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here goes the expression:

```
=Fields!DayOfWeek.Value+"(#PERCENT{p0})"
```